# Typeit.js type random strings from array

Tags: javascript, animation, typing, typeit

This is the current code and it works, but as you can see I have to manually add code for each element in the array. I want to have more elements in the array. Is it possible to code to loop through each element in `TypeIt.js` If it could randomly picked (or shuffled) instead of linear, that would be better too.

```js
var id="lines";
var element=document.getElementById(id);
var content=[
  "Example sentence one",
  "Another example string two",
  "String three",
  "Another Example String, long sentence, sentence four"
];
var p = 100;

new TypeIt("#lines",{loop:true})

  .type(content[0])
  .pause(p)
  .delete(0-element.innerText.length)

  .type(content[1])
  .pause(p)
  .delete(0-element.innerText.length)

  .type(content[2])
  .pause(p)
  .delete(0-element.innerText.length)

  .type(content[3])
  .pause(p)
  .delete(0-element.innerText.length)

  .go();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeit@7.0.4/dist/typeit.min.js"></script>

<div id="lines"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of chaining directly after initializing the TypeIt instance you could save it to a variable. Then use a loop to add all the strings to the instance. After you've added the strings you can call the `go` method to kickstart it all.

```js
var id = "lines";
var element = document.getElementById(id);
var content = [
  "Example sentence one",
  "Another example string two",
  "String three",
  "Another Example String, long sentence, sentence four"
];

var p = 100;

const instance = new TypeIt("#lines", {loop: true});

for(const str of content) {
  instance.type(str).pause(p).delete(0 - str.length);
}

instance.go();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeit@7.0.4/dist/typeit.min.js"></script>

<div id="lines"></div>
```